# Creating a new column in a pandas csv file through conditions

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing

I've searched thoroughly for hours for an answer to this, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything.

I have a csv file that looks like on the picture.
[image]

What I want to do is, for example, create a new column where every row is 0, except if month==1 **and** day>11. I did something similar, I made a new column with all rows=0 when hour>8 and hour<20, and the rest are ones:

```
dataTest['day_or_night'] = 0

dataTest['day_or_night'][dataTest['hour'] < 8] = 1

dataTest['day_or_night'][dataTest['hour'] > 20] = 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new'] = np.where((df.month==1) & (df.day>11), 1 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

convert the boolean expression of your condition for `1` and convert it to `int`

```
dataTest['day_or_night'] = (
    dataTest.day.gt(11) & dataTest.month.eq(1)
).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: This works awesomely. Just another question: is it possible to add more conditions somehow? I've tried with 
`df['ispitna'] = (
    (df.day.gt(11) & df.month.eq(1)) or (df.day.lw(3) & df.month.eq(2)) or (df.day.gt(26) & df.month.eq(3))
    or (df.day.lw(3) & df.month.eq(4)) or (df.day.gt(16)& df.month.eq(5))
).astype(np.uint8)`

but obviously, it doesn't work...

Comment: @saremisona yes, that should work... I can't guarantee your logic.  But the idea is sound.

Comment: I keep getting the same error..
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @saremisona my bad, I should have seen it.  Don't use `or`.  Use `|`.  `df['ispitna'] = ( (df.day.gt(11) & df.month.eq(1)) | (df.day.lw(3) & df.month.eq(2)) | (df.day.gt(26) & df.month.eq(3)) | (df.day.lw(3) & df.month.eq(4)) | (df.day.gt(16)& df.month.eq(5)) ).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!